# meaning of giving substance

Tags: meaning

I could not find the definition of giving substance from my bilingual dictionaries and could not infer also from example sentences? Could you help out?

Comment: Let me ask explicitly, can one use this verb instead of "to support"? e.g. supporting a theory and giving substance to a theory.

Comment: Without examples in context, that's an open question. The two phrases do not always mean the same thing, but they cover the same ground sometimes.

Comment: Maybe as an answer you can provide us with examples in which they have the same meaning and in which they have different ones. I'd appreciate that.

Comment: "To give substance" is to support or strengthen an assessment by providing proofs, competent evidence, references, experience results, strong reasoning, ...

Comment: Sounds like sustenance, which is nourishment (to feed or support). You mention samples but don't provide them, putting your post in danger of closing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you "give substance" to something, you obviously add to it something that one might call "substance".

This can be the generic meaning of "substance", meaning any sort of tangible material -- dirt, salt, sulfur, steel -- or it can be figurative "substance", meaning that something (such as a theory) which originally was "insubstantial" (eg, lacking evidence as to its validity) is "given" a property (eg, evidence to support it) that makes the theory (more) "substantial".

You may see the idiom used in a number of different contexts:  Leaked emails "give substance" to accusations of malfeasance on the part of some public official, test results "give substance" to a company's claim that it has solved the fission energy problem, an amazing performance on the part of an actor "gives substance" to the claims that he's the next Laurence Olivier.

Comment: Your answer led me to think that I can use it instead of "giving a meaning".

Comment: @MertAktaş - Yes, it could be used in that sense.  However, one should be a little wary, as it would be easy to muck up if you don't have a "feel" for the idiom.